# VB script + automate CLI command by VB script

Tags: shell, vbscript

I write the following VB script in order to run the CLI command - **vpnclient.exe**

my target is to  automate the vpnclcient process and answer “y” when question appears,

I have WIN XP PC

During running the vpnclient.exe in CMD window we get then following question

```
     Do you wish to continue? (y/n):
```

In my VB I write the “echo y” in order to answer on this question automatically 
but question is still stuck in CMD window ,and I cant continue

please advice what chuld be wrong in my code and how to fix it?

MY VB script (vpnclient.exe – exist under VPN directory)

```
 Dim oShell
 Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
 oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\Program Files\Cisco\VPN  & ( echo y | vpnclient.exe connect  ""site moon"" )"
    Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by creating a file with the commands to be executed on the command line instead of echoing the password.

Here's an example where a text file is created first with the required command and then those commands are invoked from the file.

```
Public Function FTPDownload(serverName, ftpuser, ftppassword, dirPath, localpath, fileName) 
    Dim fso, myfile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Create FTP.EXE commands file
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myfile= fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Regression\Results\ftp_cmd.ini", 2, True)
    myfile.WriteLine("open " &serverName ) 
    myfile.WriteLine(ftpuser)
    myfile.WriteLine(ftppassword)
    myfile.WriteLine("lcd " & localpath )
    myfile.WriteLine("cd " & dirPath)
    myfile.WriteLine("prompt")
    myfile.WriteLine("cr")
    myfile.WriteLine("mget *" &fileName &"*" )
    myfile.WriteLine("mdelete *" &fileName &"*" )
    myfile.WriteLine("close")
    myfile.WriteLine("quit")
    myfile.Close


    '====================The following code executes the FTP script. It creates a Shell object and run FTP program on top of it.===================
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    objShell.Run ("ftp -i -s:" & chr(34) & "C:\Regression\Results\ftp_cmd.ini" & chr(34))
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Function
```